# How to find if a class is super class of my class instance

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I have tried and failed to find a way in Pharo to find if a specific class instance has specific class as super class. By super class I am not referring only on the class that is a subclass of, but also all other classes that are up its inheritance line.

I thought that there would be a message in Object >> isSubclassOf: but alas i cant located such message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not clearly sure what do you want to find, but if you want to see if *anObject* is and instance of *aClass* or it's superclasses, you can use:

```
anObject isKindOf: aClass
```

If you want to see if *anObject* (class) inherits from *aClass*, then you use:

```
anObject inheritsFrom: aClass
```

Comment: so if I understand you, isKindOf: works with instances , while inheritsFrom: works with classes ? In my case aAnObject is an instance of a class lets call it X and I want to find if this object's class inherits from another Class lets call it Y.

Comment: ps: I tried with isKindOf: and it worked so thank you

Comment: But as Uko said, `isKindOf:` also answers true, if the object is instance of the argument, not only if it is instance of a superclass of the argument. So `'Kilon' isKindOf: ByteString` answers true, whereas `'Kilon' class isSubclassOf: ByteString` answers false.

Answer (score 1):

Only a class can be the subclass of another class. Thus you must first get the class of your object:

```
String inheritsFrom: Collection "prints: true"
'Pharo is cool' class inheritsFrom: Collection "prints: true"
```